# Nivo slider issue in resizing window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am  using nivo slider in drupal website but here when i resize my window the slider images get stretch here is my code i have not done any changes in nivo theme default.css

```
.nivoSlider {
    height: 100% !important;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}
.nivoSlider img {
    display: none;
    height: 100% !important;
    left: 0;
    max-width: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
}
.nivo-main-image {
    display: block !important;
    height: 100% !important;
    position: relative !important;
    width: 100% !important;
}

.nivo-slice {
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 5;
}
.nivo-box {
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 5;
}
.nivo-box img {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: It would be easier if u make a fiddle example or paste a link with your website :)

Comment: There could be many things causing this issue, please post a link to your website

Comment: Please Give More Detail

Comment: @PiyushMarvaniya check this link

Comment: @tarun Please Give me Your Issues Site Link

Comment: when i resize the image get stretchered @PiyushMarvaniya

Comment: in '.nivoSlider img', '.nivoSlider' and '.nivo-main-image' you are using fixed height and with '!important'. Your images are different size. #1 thing to do - make them all same size. Otherwise it will change size of your <body> every time slide changes OR there'll be empty white space in the background of slider... Personally I would make them same size with nice same style background... (And avoid using height:100%;. Better it be auto and width:100%)